# Juju Stuck on Fetching Juju agent version 2.0.0 for amd64

Tags: server, juju, maas, orchestra

I have installed the MAAS and all my nodes are ready to be deployed but when I bootstrap with juju it fails at the end. Below is the terminal printed during the bootstrapping:

```
juju bootstrap --config bootstrap-timeout=2000 maas
Creating Juju controller "maas" on maas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.0.0 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on maas...
 - 4y3h7x (arch=amd64 mem=8G cores=4)  
Fetching Juju GUI 2.2.1
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 192.168.1.152:22
Logging to /var/log/cloud-init-output.log on the bootstrap machine
Running apt-get update
Running apt-get upgrade
Installing curl, cpu-checker, bridge-utils, cloud-utils, tmux
Fetching Juju agent version 2.0.0 for amd64
```

It stuck in Fetching juju agent. I turned off the server after almost 24 hours of waiting for bootstrapping :) :/

**UPDATE:**

I checked the node monitor, it shows an error:

```
handler.py[WARNING]: failed posting event:...
```

And even though juju is not complete yet, MAAS change the node status to Deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to me that your Juju node doesn't have internet connectivity. SSH to juju node with the following command:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@<juju-node-ip>
# where you can get juju node ip from maas
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks @Junaid . I thought MaaS will configure the NAT. I configured it manually and juju is deployed.